# Any danger of using PHP getimagesize function?

Tags: php

I have this host that disables allow_url_fopen as they said it is a security risk which in turns prevents my use of getimagesize function because I am passing in a http.

My site is on Wordpress and I am using getimagesize to pull in a image within the uploads folder of a Wordpress site which obviously contains http://.

So my question is if this is not safe?  If it is not safe, how can this be done within a Wordpress environment?

Thanks.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` can be dangerous, but, `getimagesize` I think not.

Comment: yes however allow_url_fopen would have to be enable to do what I need to do.  Any other way you know?  I know passing in a server environment would be safe $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] however that may not be possible as I am using Wordpress native functions to pull the image from the wp-content/uploads folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok the solution is to use CURL.  So something like this would work.

```
$filename = "http://www.example.com/example.jpg";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $filename);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$new_image = ImageCreateFromString($contents);
imagejpeg($new_image, "temp.jpg",100);

$size = getimagesize("temp.jpg");

// width and height

$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The security risk your host is likely thinking of is where folks will try to `include()` a script from a remote host.  When you enable your fopen wrappers for HTTP, this typically gets enabled to.  (The behavior can of course be disabled, but most hosts don't bother, and just block these requests out of an abundance of caution.  Other problems exist as well.)

As far as the security of `getimagesize()` goes, it doesn't matter how you got your source image.  cURL or fopen wrappers... makes no difference.  It is mostly secure to use `getimagesize()` on arbitrary content, but watch out as vulnerabilities in various image librarys have been discovered in the past.